# How do I observe this recursive function with GHood or Vacuum?

Tags: haskell, vacuum

I'm using GHood to watch the execution of this implementation of the partition function and expected to see a binary tree. Instead I get this tree:
[image]

```
import Debug.Observe

p :: (Observable a, Ord a, Num a) => a -> a -> a
p k n 
  | k > n = 0
  | k == n = 1
  | otherwise = (observe "left" p (k+1) n ) + (observe "right" p k (n-k))

>>> printO $ observe  "p" p 1 3
```

I've also unsuccessfully tried using lazy natural numbers from `Data.Number.Natural` as per a suggestion on irc.

When using `Vacuum.Cairo` I get even less back, just the result of the function run to completion.

```
>>> m: + System.Vacuum.Cairo
>>> view $ p 1 5
```

Comment: Vacuum is meant to visualize heap structures, not evaluation, so it is no surprise you do not find what you expect there.